# Buffer undefined when using Javascript SDK in Cloudflare Worker

Tags: solana-client-sdk

I am trying to use the Solana web3 SDK in a Sveltekit app on Cloudflare pages.

For the frontend, we were able to manually import Buffer and add it to the window.
And that works great.

Since Cloudflare workers don't have a Nodejs environment, the standard buffer import does not work.

What I have tried so far:

- Manually import the buffer module for browsers (@solana/web3.js/node_modules/buffer)
- Create a global variable Buffer and add the imported module (@solana/web3.js/node_modules/buffer)
- Use the iife version of the SDK.

All the above returned the error: Buffer is not defined.

Has anyone used @solana/web3.js on a Cloudflare worker?
How were you able to circumvent the buffer issue?

Thanks!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it’s not specific to Solana. This is almost certainly because the scaffold uses a build system that no longer polyfills Node global like Buffer. See stackoverflow.com/a/68723223

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to add a shim for `Buffer`.

Install `@rollup/plugin-inject` and import it into `vite.config.js`

```
import inject from '@rollup/plugin-inject';
```

Add a `build` property to the `config` object:

```
build: {
  rollupOptions: {
    plugins: [
      inject({
        Buffer: ['buffer', 'Buffer'],
        include: '/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/**/*'
      })
    ]
  }
}
```

Your `vite.config.js` should look like this:

```
import { sveltekit } from '@sveltejs/kit/vite';
import inject from '@rollup/plugin-inject';


/** @type {import('vite').UserConfig} */
const config = {
  plugins: [sveltekit()],
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      plugins: [
        inject({
          Buffer: ['buffer', 'Buffer'],
          include: '/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/**/*'
        })
      ]
    }
  }
};

export default config;
```

Full config can be seen in the [svelte dapp starter](https://github.com/solana-developers/dapp-scaffold-svelte/blob/main/vite.config.js)

Comment: I wasn't able to create a vite.config.js because it doesn't work with Sveltekit. In svelte.config.js there is a vite key where the exact same config can be added, so that is what I did. Unfortunately, I still get the same error "Buffer is not defined" when deploying on Cloudflare.  The npm package 'buffer' has also been added to the dependencies. The strange thing is that I can import Buffer in the endpoint function, but it somehow the Solana SDK can't access it. Any idea what I am missing here?

Comment: In the latest version of svelte, there is a separate vite config file. Take a look at the svelte dapp starter and copy the config: https://github.com/solana-developers/dapp-scaffold-svelte/blob/main/vite.config.js

Comment: The config from the scaffold app ended up not solving the issue. I also tried to start with a fresh scaffold app and test just the api code there. That resulted in the exact same error: https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/2006/dapp-scaffold-svelte-on-cloudflare-cant-use-solana-web3-js-in-endpoint.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138523/discussion-between-john-and-c-og).