# dapp-scaffold-svelte on Cloudflare: can't use @solana/web3.js in endpoint

Tags: web3.js, javascript

When using the dapp-scaffold-svelte app on Cloudflare, I can't get the SDK to work in an endpoint (handled on the server).

below is the code of test version for disbursement api that we are trying to build src/routes/test/disburse.json.js

```
import {
    Keypair,
    Transaction,
    SystemProgram,
    LAMPORTS_PER_SOL,
    Connection,
    sendAndConfirmTransaction,
    clusterApiUrl,
    PublicKey
} from '@solana/web3.js';

export async function post({ request }) {
    try {
        const { receiverPubkey } = await request.json();

        const toPubkey = new PublicKey(receiverPubkey);

        const fromPubKey = '35MyDYi1XTYuCTMPvR3K7uzXuN2yU5tDLBg4Pg3JVz1o';

        const secretKeyArray = ["secret key not shown here"];

        const secretKeyByteArray = Uint8Array.from(secretKeyArray);

        const disbursementKeypair = Keypair.fromSecretKey(secretKeyByteArray, { skipValidation: true });

        const network = 'devnet';

        const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl(network), {
            commitment: 'confirmed',
            fetch: fetch.bind(globalThis)
        });

        let transaction = new Transaction();

        transaction.add(
            SystemProgram.transfer({
                fromPubkey: disbursementKeypair.publicKey,
                toPubkey,
                lamports: 0.01 * LAMPORTS_PER_SOL
            })
        );

        const result = await sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, transaction, [disbursementKeypair]);

        return {
            body: {
                success: network,
                result
            }
        };
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('error in disbursement', error);

        return {
            body: {
                error: error.message
            }
        };
    }
}
```

This is using a fresh copy of https://github.com/solana-developers/dapp-scaffold-svelte with the @sveltejs/adapter-cloudflare running on Cloudflare pages.

The error message is: Buffer is not defined.

What am I missing here?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it’s not specific to Solana. This is almost certainly because the scaffold uses a build system that no longer polyfills Node global like `Buffer`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/68723223

Comment: Also, duplicate of https://solana.stackexchange.com/q/1944/75. I can’t vote-to-close as such because I already voted to close for a different reason.

Comment: Thanks for your response @steveluscher! I started a new question (from https://solana.stackexchange.com/q/1944/75) because this seemed specific to https://github.com/solana-developers/dapp-scaffold-svelte. If it's more clear to continue this in the original question, I'd be happy to re-open it.

Comment: I recommend that you close this and open it on stackoverflow.com. That’s the appropriate place for questions that are fundamentally about JavaScript in general, and not Solana specifically.